What's the probability that $n + k^2$ is a perfect square, for fixed $n$?
What's the probability that $n + k^2$ is a perfect square, for fixed $n$ where $k$ runs from $1$ to $N$, where we can take the limit as $N \rightarrow \infty$.  We can write this as
$$P\left({n}\right) = \lim_{N \rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{N} \sum_{k = 1}^{N} \left[{\sqrt{{k}^{2} + n} \in \mathbb{Z}}\right]$$
where $[...]$ are the Iverson brackets.
My initial attempt was to say the of the number of values of $k$ that there are $\sqrt{N}$ cases that are perfect squares.  Now this argument is based on this sequence being consecutive integers.  Assuming that the ${k}^{2} + n$ are near equally distributed then there would be $\sqrt{N}$ values (i.e., perfect squares) for a probability being $\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}$.  Numerical testing shows that this is no where the case.  Numerical testing shows something like $\frac{1}{{N}^{1/4}}$ instead (not a lot of data for this at the moment).
The converse problem is the probability that ${k}^{2} + n$ is not a perfect square.  In this case I can write
$${P}^{\prime} \left({n}\right) = \lim_{N \rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{N} \sum_{k = 1}^{N} \left[{\sqrt{{k}^{2} + n} \not\in \mathbb{Z}}\right] = \frac {1}{N}\sum_{k = 1}^{N} 1 \sim 1$$
Since most cases are not a perfect square.  Numerically this is what I see with the difference (this would be the original problem statement) is $O \left({1}\right)$ which corresponds to the posted solution.

$n+k^2 = m^2$ implies $n=(m-k)(m+k)$ ; so as soon as $k>n$, we are sure that $m+k^2$ is not a perfect square.

For any fixed value of $n$, there are only finitely many positive integers $k$ such that $n+k^2$ is a perfect square.
Proof:
Suppose $n+k^2=m^2$ for some positive integer $m$. Then $m^2-k^2=n$ so $(m+k)(m-k)=n$. Since $m>k$, we have $m-k\ge1$, and $2k<m+k\le n$ so $k<n/2$.
Therefore, $$\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} \left[{\sqrt{{k}^{2} + n} \in \mathbb{Z}}\right]<n/2.$$
Your limit is:
$$P(n)=\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\left(\frac1{N}\sum_{k=1}^{N} \left[{\sqrt{k^2+n}\in\mathbb{Z}}\right]\right)<\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\left(\frac1{N}\cdot\frac n2\right)=0$$
so it is $0$.

The question in effect asks how many ways can an arbitrary number $n$ be represented as the difference of two squares?
The simple answer to that is: The number  of ways is equal to the number of divisors $d$ of $n$ that are smaller than $\sqrt{n}$ such that $d\equiv \frac{n}{d} \bmod 2$
Assume $n=m^2-k^2=(m-k)(m+k)$. OP states $k\ge 1$, so the $k=0$ trivial solution, to wit $n$ is itself a square, and $n=m^2$, is not to be considered. $(m-k),(m+k)$ have the same parity. If $(m-k),(m+k)$ are both even, $n$ is even and a multiple of $4$ or some higher power of $2$.
The best way to understand the simple answer is to consider the well known fact that the square of any positive integer $a$ is equal to the sum of the first $a$ odd numbers, viz: $$a^2=\sum_{i=1}^a(2i-1)$$
Consequently, the difference of two squares is: $$m^2-k^2=\sum_{i=k+1}^m(2i-1)$$
By the formulas regarding sums of arithmetic series, this represents the product of $(m-k)$ terms whose average value is $(m+k)$. We can identify $(m-k)$ as a divisor $d$ and $(m+k)$ as the corresponding $\frac{n}{d}$
Case 1. $n$ is  odd: Then every divisor of $n$ (including $1$) is odd, so for each such odd divisor $d<\sqrt{n}$ of $n$, there is a series of $d$ consecutive odd numbers that average to the odd number $\frac{n}{d}$. In addition to the odd number $\frac{n}{d}$ itself, there will be $\frac{d-1}{2}$ odd numbers greater than $\frac{n}{d}$ and $\frac{d-1}{2}$ odd numbers less than $\frac{n}{d}$ in the series, viz: $\frac{n}{d}, \frac{n}{d}\pm 2,\frac{n}{d}\pm 4, \dots, \frac{n}{d}\pm (d-1)$. This series features $d$ consecutive odd numbers of average value $\frac{n}{d}$, so its sum is just $n$.
Case 2. $n$ is  even: Then for every even divisor of $n$, $d<\sqrt{n}$ of $n$ and $d\equiv \frac{n}{d} \equiv 0 \bmod 2$, there is a series of $d$ consecutive odd numbers that average to the even number $\frac{n}{d}$. There will be $\frac{d}{2}$ odd numbers greater than $\frac{n}{d}$ and $\frac{d}{2}$ odd numbers less than $\frac{n}{d}$ in the series, viz: $\frac{n}{d}\pm 1,\frac{n}{d}\pm 3, \dots, \frac{n}{d}\pm (d-1)$. This series features $d$ consecutive odd numbers of average value $\frac{n}{d}$, so its sum is just $n$.
The $i$th odd number is $2i-1$. The largest odd number $z$ in any such series is the $m$th odd number, where $m=\frac{z+1}{2}$, and the $k$th odd number is just $m-d$, which yields $n=m^2-k^2$.
